# Merge dataframes with default match on left only rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, left-join, python-3.5

I have two `data frames`, and I want to merge them by a key that exists in both `UserId`.

However, if for any row in `df1` there is no matching id in `df2`, I want to set some default merge value, specifically `df2[df2.UserId == 0]`, which always exists in `df2`.

I thought about merging left with indicator, then filling all the rows that didn't match left, but I'm not sure how to set the content of `df2` into these rows without specifically specifying each column.

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on=['UserId'], how='left', sort=False, indicator=True)
res[res._merge == 'left_only'] = ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, on=['UserId'], how='left', sort=False, indicator=True)

defaultDicts = [extractDefault(row, df2) for index, row in res.loc[res._merge == 'left_only'].iterrows()]
defaultPd = pd.DataFrame(defaultDicts)

res = res[res._merge == 'both']
res = res.append(defaultPd, ignore_index=False)[res.columns.tolist()]
res.drop('_merge', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

With the following additional definition:

```
def extractDefault(resRow, df2):
    defaultRow = df2[df2.UserId == 0)].iloc[0]
    resDict = resRow.to_dict()
    defaultDict = defaultRow.to_dict()
    mergedDict = { **resDict, **defaultDict }
    return mergedDict
```